# Is there any React Native library that can navigate to Google maps app with directions and multiple waypoints?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps, directions, google-maps-urls

I want to be able to open Google maps app from my app and get directions with multiple waypoints from my apps data.

Comment: Have a look at [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action). Directions mode supports origin, destination and waypoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this libraryr [react-native-directions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-maps-directions) . . There you can provide the lat , long and it will open the maps with . directions. Under the hood it only calls `Linking` of `react-native` with

```
const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&${getParams(
    params
  )}${getWaypoints(waypoints)}`
```

So you can either do it like this or use the library.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.